PayPal Pay Later Doesn't Work Magento ver. 2.4.6-p3
I have configure pay later on my site. I have setup every config correctly and all integration and pay later settings are well.

The pay later not shows on product page,cart page,checkout page. I have spent on this issues 2 days but not found any solution. I have applied multi settings and follow the Paypal official site guide but pay later button not show also when I enable 
This option then pay later does work and show but not show price I have the correct merchant id and everything. Also when I enable the context checkout experience then in checkout page when we choose Paypal as a payment method then place order button doesn't work. I have tried to do this. Please help me anyone who can know th
